# Merge Statement and Identity Insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I am using Merge statement to Insert/Update data in my stored procedure.

```
MERGE [dbo].[tReserveData_4541] AS Target
USING (SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[tblcangrowhitesh]) AS Source
ON ( [Source].[PK_ID] =  [Target].[PK_ID])

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET [Target].[mgender] = Source.[mgender]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([Granularity], [PK_ID], [ROWID], 
            [mgender], [mma1], [mma2], [mma3], 
            [mmadmincost], [mmcumulativevolume], 
            [mmcurrency], [mmdate],
            [mmfileimporteddate], [mmfilename])
    VALUES ([Source].[Granularity], [Source].[PK_ID], [Source].[ROWID],
            [Source].[mgender], [Source].[mma1], [Source].[mma2], [Source].[mma3], 
            [Source].[mmadmincost], [Source].[mmcumulativevolume],
            [Source].[mmcurrency], [Source].[mmdate],
            [Source].[mmfileimporteddate], [Source].[mmfilename])
```

As you can see I am going to insert identity column i.e. `[PK_ID]` in the `MERGE` statement. But I am unable to do so.

Comment: Have you tried not inserting the PK_ID? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Your target table shouldn't have an identity column if you want to have it sync with another table (that one should have the identity column).

Answer (score 10):

I'm not that familiar with the `MERGE` command, but as you're inserting directly into an identity column, would you not have to use the IDENTITY_INSERT command? e.g.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tReserveData_4541] on

MERGE...

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tReserveData_4541] off
```

Comment: ...and I think there's something about *having* to end the entire MERGE statement with a semicolon;

Comment: another interesting vector to this answer is your WHEN MATCHED clause... make sure you are not SET [IdentityColumn] = ___

Answer (score 0):

Remove the IDENTITY property on PK_ID if you don't need to generate values on the target.

To do this you can add a PK_ID_temp column `UPDATE [dbo].[tReserveData_4541] SET PK_ID_temp = PK_ID`. Drop the PK_ID column then rename PK_ID_temp back to PK_ID.

This may also require dropping the Primary Key, dropping any associated indexes and rebuilding all non-clustered indexes if it is a clustered index.